# Legends display order using highcharts in pie chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

Using highcharts, legends are displayed in a horizontal manner. I am trying to display in vertical order (one series below the other) but I could not find any solutions for that.

In the image below, the order of legends are horizontal. Can someone help me figure out how to display the legend in a vertical order?
[image]

Comment: What you tried so far. Share your code here.

Comment: learn your api's and rtm : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.layout

Comment: @Lordkain, Thanks for providing link of API charts, I got what I was looking for. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Use this snippet, it will place the label vertically in bottom of chart:

```
  legend: {    
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            layout: 'vertical        
        },
```

You can check it with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/guL2198j/) fiddler.